# Rails 3.2.11 - Set permanent or temporary cookie based on a checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, session-cookies

I'm facing a basic problem and probably need fresh eyes to help me solve it.

I have a basic authentication system wich works fine. Now I would like to set a permanent cookie only if user checks the 'Remember me' check box on the login form, and a temporary cookie (that expires at the end of session) if the "Remember me" check box is not check.

My SessionsController is

```
def create
user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  if params[:session][:remember_me]
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  else
    cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end
  sign_in user

  redirect_back_or root_path
else
  flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
  render 'new'
end
```

end

The SessionsHelper is

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user) 
  self.current_user = user
end
```

The problem is that the permanent cookie is always set, despite the checkbox is not checked...
What am I missing ?

Thanks for your help

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be with the line:

`if params[:session][:remember_me]`

That will probably be a string with a value of '0' or '1' depending on whether the checkbox has been checked. Your `if` will be being interpreted as:

`if params[:session][:remember_me] != nil`

Which will be true if it's '0' or '1'. Note that as everything is an object in Ruby even if it was an integer you'd have the same problem. Try the following in irb:

`puts 'Hello World' if 0`

Spoiler - it'll print 'Hello World' ;-)

If you instead check that it's not '0' then it should work:

`if params[:session][:remember_me] != '0'`